# Upgrade from previous Visual Studio Setup to Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix-extension

I had an old installer which was a basic visual studio setup project however after some time we realized that it was just no where near as complex as we need. So I've spent a few days generating a replacing with WiX.

Now my current problem is upgrading from the previous installs. If someone has installed one of the versions that was installed with the VS Project, is it possible for them to use the new WiX project? I have tried with setting the upgrade codes the same but it's not making any different, it seems to think its a completely new product and tries to install again.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the help topic: [How To: Implement a Major Upgrade In Your Installer](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/major_upgrade.htm)

Major Upgrades can only perform upgrades in the same installation context. (Per User -> Per User or Per Machine -> Per Machine ).   If your VDPROJ was installed Per-User by accident then the user will have to uninstall / reinstall to become Per-Machine.

Your new installer doesn't have to have the same UpgradeCode as the old installer but it does have to author the MajorUpgrade using the UpgradeCode from the old installer.

Comment: How can last sentence be implemented in wix project? What is the code for it?

Comment: Read the help topic link. (Hint: MajorUpgrade element)

Comment: It seems that MajorUpgrade element works with Upgrade table (created with [Upgrade](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_upgrade.htm) elements).

Comment: Correct. WiX is a thin abstraction (transformation) over Windows Installer. Where WI is a relation database,  WiX is XML with an XSD.   The MajorUpgrade element is a bit of syntactical sugar that further simplifies the Upgrade element and related sequencing of the RemoveExistingProducts action.  The underlying Windows Installer schema / SDK is fully declarative and fully documented.  There really isn't anything "black box" about it.  It's wide open and rich in metadata.

Comment: The per machine / per user got me confused trying to figure out why WiX wouldn't remove (or detect with UpgradeVersion) the Visual Studio Installer previous version of a co-worker.

Comment: Strictly speaking, WiX doesn't do the remove anyways.  Windows Installer does.  WiX merely authors Windows Installer databases. The distinction is lost on many new WiX users because they don't have the underlying Windows Installer exposure.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible, but several things need to be set up correctly. Maybe what you see in .vdproj project is not the same as what is written in .msi installation. Use Orca as .msi reader, and extract every needed information. Upgrade code must be the same, product code must be different, and installation version must be larger, in either first, second, or third number. Fourth number does not count.

WiX is like a obscure black box to me too, so I could be missing something, but to my knowledge if all is set up like stated above then the old installation should be automatically uninstalled when you start new installation. There is a [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx) that explains some of it.

EDIT: Upgrade code does not have to be the same, but then you have to do additional work, hopefully as described in this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-8-major-upgrade.aspx).

Comment: The problem was I didn't change first or second build numbers. It was 3.3.1.1, i tried first to change to 3.3.1.2 but it didnt work. Then made it 3.4.0.0 and walla, it upgraded correctly

Comment: If WiX is an obsecure black box to you, why are you trying to answer this question?  Your assertion that third and fourth numbers don't count is wrong.  The fourth number doesn't count.  Also the two MSI's don't have to have the same UpgradeCode.  You also didn't mention needing an entry in the Upgrade table. This is where the old UpgradeCode is needed.